# What is the difference in the execution of callback of 'click' event triggered by the user and that triggered programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

I was going through an article of Jake Archibald on tasks, microtasks etc. In his example we see that the 'console logs' are printed in certain order for user based click event and different order for click event triggered programmatically. I request if someone could please explain it in a bit more detail about click callback execution in these two cases.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-test"><div class="inner-test"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer-test {
  background: #D4D4D4;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 92px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner-test {
  background: #ADADAD;
  padding: 46px;
  width: 0;
}
```

**JS(First case)**

```
var outer = document.querySelector('.outer-test');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner-test');


new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('mutate');
}).observe(outer, {
  attributes: true
});


function onClick() {
  console.log('click');

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout');
  },0);

  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise');
  });

  outer.setAttribute('data-random', Math.random());
}


inner.addEventListener('click', onClick);
outer.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

**JS(Second Case)**

```
var outer = document.querySelector('.outer-test');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner-test');


new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('mutate');
}).observe(outer, {
  attributes: true
});


function onClick() {
  console.log('click');

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout');
  },0);

  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise');
  });

  outer.setAttribute('data-random', Math.random());
}


inner.addEventListener('click', onClick);
outer.addEventListener('click', onClick);

inner.click();  //<========
```

For reference: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Answer (score 0):

> .click() causes the event to dispatch synchronously, so the script that calls .click() is still in the stack between callbacks.

He glances over the answer but that's basically it. Not going to pretend I fully understand the details but as I read it: since the click is triggered from within the JavaScript in the same "frame" as the code that is setting up the event listeners AND triggering the event this way is synchronous the callbacks are run directly after because it doesn't allow to check the microtask queue for the mutation.

In the first case the "setup" finishes and that "frame" ends. So it's only by clicking in the browser that things fire, which will then happen in another frame (asynchronously) and since no other "frame" is running at that point it goes ahead and check the microtask queue for the mutation first.

> The above rule ensures microtasks don't interrupt JavaScript that's mid-execution.

And this seems to be the reason for why that isn't done which makes sense since it's all single threaded (you know, sort of) that it makes sense to let that "frame" finish.

So the quirk is really in that firing a event programatically forces it all into synchronous land.